# Laravel makes API get data from database using authurization token

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make an API that will fetch a paticual users all data when token is passed in headers as authorization token.

I am new to Laravel and back-end I have generated token using Laravel passport.

[image]

api.php
`Route::get('/{user}', [userData::class, 'get_all']);`

userData.php

what I have tried is passing the id but I don't want that

```php
public function get_all(User $user)
{
  
 dd($user);
 $user = User::where('id', $user)->first();
 return response()->json([
    'user' => $user,
 ]);    
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The call in your Postman is different than your route. Show the result of `dd($user)`. What is the response you're getting in your Postman? Show screenshot

Comment: @UnderDog i have added screenshot of dd($user) pls not  i dont want to pass id i want to pass only user token and fetch data

Comment: The difficult part is that you're doing `User::where('id', $user)`. So keep that in mind, but I think you want to get the profile. So this is not the answer, but if you remove {user} from your route, you're doing `http://localhost/api/`. Let's sat you want "getdata". In your route, you do: `Route::get('/getdata` and then add the proper function, like you've already done. Now ... think of this one: how are you getting the data of only that single user?

Comment: i dont undersatand what u are trying to say pls chek the new screen shot thre is clint id three and user_id there of user with that i want to pass cliet_id as token and feach data of corresponding  user_id